Why can't I run Linux on my laptop?
I don't know the reason way I can't run any distro on my laptop (Dell latitude E7470) I try Ubuntu, Debian, Kali Linux Arch and more distros all of them have the same problem.
I finish installing I restart when I launch OS after an amount of time it depends, sometimes in the log in screen or after a while of using it, completely freezes and the only solution is to shut down by the button.
I try a lot of solution but nothing work, I don't know what to do. I know I am only using in VM but I wan't to learn about Linux more by run it as my primary OS.
Here are the specs:

Processor: Intel i5 - 6300U
RAM: 16GB
Storage: 500GB (NVMe)
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 520

Here are the steps I go through to attempt to install Ubuntu, for example:

Power on the laptop.
Press F12 to enter the boot menu.
From the boot menu, select USB Storage (where Ubuntu is installed on the external M.2 drive).
Ubuntu starts booting normally, showing the GRUB screen.
The login screen appears as expected.
When I try to type password at the login screen, everything freezes.
The only way to recover from the freeze is to force shut down the laptop by holding the power button.



We can't know what the problem is unless you give us more detail. Pick one distro, a stable and broadly supported one like Ubuntu (don't use Kali until you're familiar with Linux), record EVERY step you take installing it and the outcome, then give us those steps and the results and output.

ok  i will upload a video

Instead of installing, also just use the Live USB functionality for an extended time. Does it freeze, too? Maybe also install an SSH server, then check whether the system is still reachable over SSH when “frozen”. (SSH clients are also available on Android/iOS.) It could be a graphics driver problem.

Don't upload a video. Take careful notes of your steps and provide them here. That is going to be more helpful than a video.

1-Power on the laptop.
2- Press F12 to enter the boot menu.
3- From the boot menu, select USB Storage (where Ubuntu is installed on the external M.2 drive).
4- Ubuntu starts booting normally, showing the GRUB screen.
5- The login screen appears as expected.
6- When i try to type  password at the login screen, everything freezes.
7- The only way to recover from the freeze is to force shut down the laptop by holding the power button.

Was it working before with Windows? Given the age of the hardware failure is a strong possibility...

As others mentioned, start by making a live USB and try booting from that USB. For example, follow the step-by-step instructions at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview . Follow Dell's directions for booting from USB: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/latitude-e7470-ultrabook/late_e7470_om/boot-sequence?guid=guid-39ea0288-9174-49b6-aba2-37c542a11fc5&lang=en-us Then edit the question to report what happened.

So you are installing Linux on a M.2 SSD in an external USB housing. That is probably the entire cause of your problem. Such external housings are, in general,  NOT designed/intended to be used as OS drive.

The last entry is related to the Gnome display manager. As mentioned, this is probably a video problem. A live-CD or USB stick can help you.

Try booting into console mode rather than gui and see if it gets further.
